# searching matlab search path with strcmp

Tags: matlab

I have written the code below. Basically it is checking if some path is already in the matlab search path or not. If it is not found then it adds the path.

The problem is the strcmp always returns a vector of zeros despite the path actually already existing in currPath. I actually copied a path from currPath to check I was getting the correct values. Not sure why this is?

```
% get current path
currPath = strsplit(path, ';')';
currPath = upper(currPath);

% check if required paths exist - if not add them
pathsToCheck = ['C:\SOMEFOLDER\MADEUP'];
pathsToCheck = upper(pathsToCheck);

for n = 1 : length(pathsToCheck(:, 1))       
    index = strcmp(currPath, pathsToCheck(n, 1));    
    if sum(index) > 0    
        addpath(pathsToCheck{t, 1}, '-end');          % add path to the end
    end    
 end

% save changes
savepath;
```

Comment: in this example, `pathsToCheck` is a `char`, so `length(pathsToCheck(:, 1))` will be the length of a single character (==1). Similarly, `pathsToCheck(n, 1)` is always a single character, so that the `strcmp` fails. So, is this only true in the example? If yes, please update :) If no, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks! That was a bit stupid of me, long day

Comment: So, was that your problem? Or just a problem in the example?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have defined `pathsToCheck` as a character array and *not* a cell array (which I think is what you intended the way that you are looping through it).

Rather than using a for loop, you could use `ismember` to check which members of a cell array of strings exist in another cell array of strings.

```
% Note the use of pathsep to make this work across multiple operating systems
currentPath = strsplit(path, pathsep);
pathsToCheck = {'C:\SOMEFOLDER\MADEUP'};

exists = ismember(pathsToCheck, currentPath);
% If you want to ignore case: ismember(upper(pathsToCheck), upper(currentPath))

% Add the ones that didn't exist
addpath(pathsToCheck{~exists}, '-end');
```